# Resource Limit Is Reached or HTTP Error 503 Service Unavailable in every site

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-chrome, http-status-codes, http-status-code-503

i am currently working on a worpress site, as i was scrolling on the products page, the page got very slow, and after some times it would be stuck and take a lot of time to load other products, then after some time i couldn't make any operation it stuck in the same place, i couldn't do any other transaction because it would always throw a 503  service unavailable or too many requests, i thought it was a plugin that did that but as i received a notification from the website host that i exceeded my limit in using of the ressources. i don't understand why it was that way as i was the only one using the site.

But then after the work, i was planning to watch any series or videos but each site i visit does the same, it would throw a 503 Service unavailable or, ressouce reached or 520 error. is it my browser then?

i tried multiple times clear cache, disable/deleting extensions, i also tried to use another browser like Opera  but the thing is happening. what do you think?

Note that some sites like youtube, stackoverflow are working normally.

Comment: using one or 1000 websites doesnt matter if you need resources and obv your hosting doesnt fit your needs. Also could be to bad query when you load your products and hitting your limit bcs of that. Consider having better hosting or do some test on your website to find your problem. As for visiting other websites and having errors could be due to many things.

Answer (score 0):

Some budget host vendors throttle their customers' CPU, IO, or bandwidth use. Your 503 makes it sound like you were throttled. And your vendor confirmed that. Your site used up some resource quota.

This can happen when cybercreeps attack your site with credential-stuffing attacks, where they try to log in with many username-password combinations. It's the classic denial-of-service attack when they don't get in, and a serious pwn of your site if they do.

It can also happen during software development or testing, where some imperfect code goes into a tight loop and burns CPU. php runtime limits help, but if the problem recurs a lot you'll reach your quotas.

You may want to switch hosting providers, or you may want to do development and testing on your own laptop.

For production, there are several security plugins to slow down cybercreeps.

Comment: thank you for your response, do you have any suggestion of what to do to make it less slower, and if you have any suggestion of some security plugins please?

Comment: I saw with the WP activity log that there was someone who tried multiple times to connect with the admin account with different ip address but failed, is it the credential-stuffing attacks? what to do in this case?